# Can't connect using ssh after enabling it on Kali Linux using the root user and password

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, kali-linux

I have enabled SSH and Port forwarded on my router to port 22 and I can't login as root user and password using putty it says access denied, and I can't connect to it using the same linux OS using the root user and password. It says Permission denied, please try again.

Can someone please let me know what I need to do to connect?

[image: SSH Can't Connect]

Comment: Is there `PermitRootLogin` line in `sshd_config` of the SSH server? What does the line say?

Comment: Also, "port forwarding" is entirely unnecessary if you're only connecting from within the same network. The only reason you'd ever do that is if you needed to be able to connect over the internet, i.e. remotely.

Comment: I edited the PermitRootLogin using sudo gedit and I changed "#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password" to "#PermitRootLogin yes" but I think I forgot to remove the # so that might be why I followed this link https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ssh-secure-shell-service-on-kali-linux

Comment: I didn't know that bob. That's good to know. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I found a way to connect. The SSH server was not enabled.

Comment: @SuperUserJL feel free to answer your own question, with how you figured it out and how you started SSH. It may help others in the future with the same problem!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To install SSH on Linux using terminal**

To see if ssh is installed on Linux (the client) to see if it is installed on the computer type:

```
ssh
```

[image: See If SSH Client Is Installed]

To see if ssh server is installed on the Linux system type:

```
ssh local host
```

local host (is the loopback IP address, the IP address that the computer uses to talk to the same Linux OS)

[image: SSH Local Host]

To install ssh server type:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

[image: Install SSH Server]

To see if the ssh server is active type this:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

[image: To See if SSH Server Is Active]

type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> after this if the terminal won't let you type anything now.

If the server is active you can type this command to start it:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

[image]

Then you can use this command to to see if it is now active:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

[image: See If SSH Server Is Active]

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> after this if the terminal won't let you type anything now.

and to stop the SSH server you can type this if want to stop it sometime:

```
sudo service ssh stop
```

you can also check the status using this command to make sure it stopped:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

If you are using Virtual Box and need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, make sure you hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button and then type <kbd>c</kbd> while still holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>; Virtual Box uses this key as default as the host key so you might have to try the other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button on the keyboard if this is not working.