# Telnet Linux and connecting with putty on Windows 10 with root user and password

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty, port

I am trying to install and enable telnet on Linux so I can connect to it using putty on Windows 10, I followed the instructions on this link: 
[Install and Enable Telnet server in Ubuntu Linux](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux)

To see if telnet is listening for incoming connections I used the command `netstat -ta` and it gave me a list of services that are listening for incoming connections.

Then used the command `nmap localhost` (local host resolved to 127.0.0.1, the ip address to test a connection on the same Linux OS) and it said port 23 is open but I can't connect to localhost using root and password and I also can not connect from Windows 10 using putty with root and password.

Pictures attached.

[image: Netstat for listening incoming connections and nmap for listening ports for the Ip address of Linux]

[image: Telnet localhost (local host 127.0.0.1 the ip address to test a connection on the same linux OS)]

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to connect to telnet using root and password?

Comment: please please please don't use telnet. Its insecure and there's better ways to remotely connect to your PC

Comment: It's not uncommon to disable root access using telnet and ssh. As others have pointed out using telnet is a bad idea security wise. If you don't have a very good reason to set this up (e.g. demonstration on how insecure it is) consider using ssh instead.

Comment: I have to do it for a college class I am taking. I guess I can see if the instructor is alright with me using SSH.

Comment: I do not understand steps 5 in this link and the part that says add these lines as you like.  http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use SSH it is more secure.

In this link I talk about how to install and enable SSH:

[Can't connect using ssh after enabling it on Kali Linux using the root user and password](https://superuser.com/questions/1361480/cant-connect-using-ssh-after-enabling-it-on-kali-linux-using-the-root-user-and)

Comment: You might want to close the loop on the question by accepting the answer.